# Firebase - How can I update an object in the Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase-realtime-database

How to update an existing object.

I'm having trouble updating an objectin the Firebase Realtime Database.

Does anyone know how to do this?

I'm using: Angular and TypeScript.

**Here is my current TypeScript code:**

```
updateProfile = (profile): any => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
    var refProfile = new Firebase("https://poolcover.firebaseio.com/profiles");

    refProfile.update(profile, function(error) {
      if (error) {
        console.log('Synchronization failed');
        resolve(false); 
      } else {
        console.log('Synchronization succeeded');
        resolve(true); 
      }
    });
  })  
}
```

**This is the database table and profile I'm looking to update:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find the key for the profile. When storing user data, you should key off of the `uid` not an id with `.push()`.

Also, don't use the completed callback use a listener instead.

A completed callback waits for a server response, where a listener fires off locally first. So a listener callback is faster.

```
constructor() {
  this.profileRef = new Firebase("<my-firebase-app>/profiles");
  var currentUser = this.profileRef.getAuth(); // if authenticated 
  this.userRef = refProfile.child(currentUser.uid);
  userRef.on('value', (snap) => {
    console.log('Profile updated');
    console.log(snap.val()); // update profile info
  });
}

updateProfile(profile) {
  this.userRef.update(profile);
}
```

Comment: Thanks David I will try this today

Comment: If the above code you wrote getUser();
Did you mean getAuth();?